# How do I do right-click the icons on the  Unity launcher using keyboard keys?

Tags: 11.04, unity, shortcut-keys, quicklists

Is there way to do get right click action on unity dash board icon launcher using keyboard shortcut ?. After doing Alt+F1, I could select the application only.

Comment: You cannot right-click on the dash icons using either the mouse or the keyboard..Maybe you are referring to the icons on the launcher...

Comment: yes. i meant, icons on the launcher.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use the keyboard to access the quicklists for the icons present on the unity launcher is simple.

Press Alt+F1 to put keyboard focus onto the Launcher and select the application icon using up and down arrow keys. **To access the application's quicklists press the Right Arrow key.**